# How to preserve specific string[] type in generic for omit() function?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to accurately describe a simple `omit()` function:

```js
function omit(source, props) {
   return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(source).filter(entry => {
            if (Array.isArray(props)) {
                return !props.includes(entry[0]);
            }

            return entry[0] !== props;
        }),
    );
}
```

Below I will describe three of my approaches and why they failed. If you clearly understand the problem and know the answer you can skip it and move to answer. :)

## Approach 1

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXxwFssMAeAKAEgB5eEADwxFWAGd4AlcHGYU1jDCyoA5gBp4aANaocAd1QA+CQAU6jZm3gCho+AB9tg4SIDaAXXKKAFFVY5kMMCABc8ahIAOMHJ9ZuVcgBKN2piMioPeDUGJhZ2HRN4AH5o+ADTVGRCACMQGEtFAG5yUrA8AQIARngAXgJw6wBveCg3KokctwByRBwcbokwN0FkBABfCW6c7qCS8hwqgDooIvgAenX4WToYHxh4AFp4cr3wDAXlnLXN3f2jk544TEulsButnfz749Pni7KFQwBAATHUGiRmq12p0en0BkMRjAxvBJvBTNNBvBumBuuY5qUcCCVh87jwHnIfKIAIQLYnXDZbb7k35Pc50t6k5kHVlnTBAA)

```js
declare function omit<
    O extends Record<string, unknown>, P extends string | string[]
>(
    source: O, props: P
): Omit<
    O, P extends string ? P : P[number]
>;


const o1 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, 'b');

o1.a; // no error - correct
o1.b; // error - correct
o1.c; // no error - correct


const o2 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, ['b', 'c']);

o2.a; // error - wrong!
o2.b; // error - correct
o2.c; // error - correct
```

It was the most obvious solution for me.

Unfortunately the `o2.a` expression produces an error `Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Omit<{ a: number; b: string; c: boolean; }, string>'`. Apparently, TS loses the specific string types in `string[]` and merges they in a common `string`.

## Approach 2

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXxwFssMAeAKAEgB5eEADwxFWAGd4AlcHGYU1jDCyoA5gBp4aANaocAd1QA+CVQAKARjqNmbeAKGixagExamLdvuHi1AZjM7Lg60cqqHFvc9HwAPvABtDQBdP0CNCVVjUP8g9UjjSNtg8kUACipWHGQYMBAALnhqCQAHGBwS1kLVcgBKQupiMipi+HcGc10rHwB+NvhqgNRkQgAjEBgUxQBucjmwPAECTQBeAia0gG94KEL4+FHCgHJEHBwjiTBCwWQEAF8JI9Gj2tnyHHUAOihp+AB6P7wWR0GDlGDwAC08AWoPAGHeX1GvwBILBkOhPDgmARnzAyMBwImaKhMKx8PmiwwBFMayIJC2Oz2EkO8BOZwu0OuMFu8AegSeHKOYCOwVecxwxm++KBOFRPHRpLh70lSP+gKJ8pJmKVEtx0o14K1sMwQA)

```js
declare function omit<
    O extends Record<string, unknown>, 
    P1 extends string,
    P2 extends string,
    P3 extends string,
    P extends string | [P1] | [P1, P2] | [P1, P2, P3]
>(
    source: O, props: P
): Omit<
    O, P extends string ? P : P[number]
>;


const o1 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, 'b');

o1.a; // no error - correct
o1.b; // error - correct
o1.c; // no error - correct


const o2 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, ['b', 'c']);

o2.a; // no error - correct
o2.b; // error - correct
o2.c; // error - correct
```

The approach works totally fine, but has the obvious drawback — it is impossible to use (to describe in function type) arbitrary number of properties to be omitted.

## Approach 3

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXxwFssMAeAKAEgB5eEADwxFWAGcCAjAK3AwBoqABTqNmbeKwwwsqAOYBtALrkAfAApy8LRJzIYYEAC541AdvgA6KwAcYOa62ODyASmPViZU-EHzUyQg4QGEUVAG5ycjA8SQIARngAXgJPNQBveChjOL54DmMAckQcHALcsGMpZAQAX1yCjgKXCPIcOIsoMPgAem74VBw6GDsYeABaeGjh3lb2ji7eoZHxyZxpzFmLMAW+gaW1lam4Dcjo1FicACYklJJ0zOzc-PgikrLJyphq+DqXxvqwE0WlcOjt+oNgssJkcZiD5j0+pCDtC1scMK1LlswUjRij1hggA)

```js
declare function omit<
    O extends object,
    P extends string[]
>(
    source: O,
    ...props: P
): Omit<O, P[number]>;

const o1 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, 'b');

o1.a; // no error - correct
o1.b; // error - correct
o1.c; // no error - correct


const o2 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, 'b', 'c');

o2.a; // no error - correct
o2.b; // error - correct
o2.c; // error - correct
```

I have stolen the solution from the immortal `lodash`'s typedefs. And to my surprise it works!

For some reason (**please** tell me if you understand why) TS saves the specific `string[]` type for the rest parameters, but not for an array in a regular parameter.

Alas, this solution is still not what I'm looking for: it uses rest parameters, not the single regular parameter.

## So...

Is there a way to describe my specific function? Why does TS save a specific `string[]` type in a generic for a rest parameters, but not for an array in a regular parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wRJK1w) meet your needs? I'm happy to write up an answer if so; otherwise please let me know what use cases it fails to satisfy.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it looks absolutely suitable! Could you please give me some explanation also? `[...P[]]` looks as some dark magic for me...

Comment: When you write `[...P[]]` it's a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) which gives the compiler a hint to infer a tuple type instead of an array.  It [probably isn't necessary though](https://tsplay.dev/NVKG5m).  Anyway it might not be until tomorrow when I write this up since it is rather late now in my time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more of an art than a science when it comes to getting the compiler to look at a string literal value like `"a"` and keep its type to be [the literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"a"` instead of widening to the `string` type.  If users of `omit()` are willing to explicitly make their intentions clear, say, by using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), then things will start working for you even with approach #1:

```
const o2 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, ['b' as const, 'c' as const]);
o2.a; // okay
o2.b; // error 
o2.c; // error
```

---

Otherwise you are relying on the heuristic rules the compiler uses.  If you look at [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) you can see a list of these rules.

The approach that works for me most consistently is: make a generic type parameter that is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string` (for string literals), like `P extends string`, and then use that type parameter everywhere I want the compiler to treat string literals as a string literal type.  That leads to the following implementation of `omit()`:

```
declare function omit<
    O extends Record<string, unknown>, P extends string
>(
    source: O, props: P | P[]
): Omit<O, P>;
```

Now you can see that everything behaves as desired:

```
const o1 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, 'b');
// function omit<{ ... }, "b">(...)
o1.a; // okay
o1.b; // error 
o1.c; // okay
    
const o2 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, ['b', 'c']);
// function omit<{ ... }, "b" | "c">(...)
o2.a; // okay
o2.b; // error
o2.c; // error
```

---

Of course, these are just inference hints and do not guarantee that someone won't overcome them:

```
const oops = ["b", "c"];
// const oops: string[]

const o3 = omit({ a: 1, b: "foo", c: true }, oops)
// const o3: Omit<{ ... }, string>
```

Here the user has declared `oops` in a way that the compiler infers `string[]` as its type.  That has happened before the `omit()` has a chance to do anything.  And so the `P` parameter is inferred to be `string` because `oops` is of type `string[]`.  And you get a useless type out of it.

I'm not sure how to suggest you proceed there.  It might not be much of a concern or you might be happy with the current outcome.  You could make it so that the compiler rejects calls to `omit()` if `P` is inferred as `string` like this:

```
declare function omit<
    O extends Record<string, unknown>, P extends string
>(
    source: O, props: string extends P ? never : P | P[]
): Omit<O, P>;
```

which works the same for the good examples, but causes the following call to warn:

```
const o3 = omit({ a: 1, b: "foo", c: true }, oops) // error!
// ----------------------------------------> ~~~~
// Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

There's certainly some diminishing returns when it comes to handling edge cases, so I'll stop belaboring the point.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4CgBIAEwngBsQ1kAzAV2HgBcMB7YJVsDJgHiMIokEAB5MIwYlCQAlMqzTFeUJpmBYANEgYBrYKwDuwAHxaACsLESpSFWpwAfW6ozqA2gF0ixgBQCorHRoiABcqFowaKwwUGFmRACUYSjcfAIo5pbiktJ2rjgA-EgWcW7AdGAARhBoXoTGANz4zYTw7CqcAIxIALycqT64SCBhnVqVYQDkNKysk1rwYap0yAC+WpOVkwlNRKydAHQgDUgA9KdI+sJoUWhIALRIbTdkTHuHlSfn17cPTwrUZjvA7wL4XK41X6PZ6At4tNrADqsABMvX6PEGw1G4ymMzmCyWaBWSHWSDcm0mw2kCJUG3glJA1PaTA8Oz2yKOYM4OhAAE92QdPmcLpCFEgBaDhT8xfhVs1SBQqLQGMw2BwuDx+IIstZpHJnko8uotLp9EZTMUdTlnPZ8L4iAEgqFwkhItFYpanGZPPgkqhUrwMsVGs18DSmF00RqmJiRkgxkgJkhprN5k9CcTSRS2d96IwWOx0XwhgdSyStAAiSoV3ylg4JfD7TlS1g8-lNoXfUV3RuHSXfVt80PhziovrR2PYxO41MEpDLNZaclbOmTVlNXMqgvqgMlsukqsVpBOCvwGs+OsNlHNgdtxsczsim4Ke8grnd4fMzjutFuQ+Vs8PA3C4R1mGIwiNLAfVAgBmKMBiGOMEyTCs8QrOcF3Lb8Ygbb5YOSXckDrLDIOMZpQEgWAEGQABVLAAAs8BaBVKGoJA81VQtoy1bVRGyGx9QUQ0XGNbRgD0QwTEyPjdRtfJvD8QhCEdYIIGSCIonAuT1CtGwLCKYAIAANxqJA4mPYofUIP0Uk1IMzBDeEv32eCMUQqckxTfF03nIlF2TLY2UITd8zVIteD3A4sMPWtSwbQgm2OFs7wSj532fHtUrfZKhycxEIxRVyY3c+McWTPE00WXzMyXClV3XIgQs4ndNUi6Lqws09z0vAUktvIcEofdLbglYaXzypEfz6P9qwAisgMakDnPdCCRKgupYKKydSunJBUNmdCfMw0kwKgBIpW7ABCRaHnuO77oex6nuel77uMJAAD8vo+m6AEE0CwCoJAKmh515GBkEmSDPEpDBpH0CNGSgbBQEqchkCYVhXSocAIHEO5WFBphwchwyTLQSYDllIA)

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant answer and for pointing to the corner case with wide-typed `props`. I used your trick with `string extends P` and created the almost perfect (in my opinion) type definition: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nn4qxW). Alas, when I tried to make it *more perfect*, the magic fell apart ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkjbLm)). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Actually, I still can not accept the fact that constrained generic type parameters are used in TS as just "hints" to the compiler to make it to preserve specific literal types. I mean, c'mon, the `omit` function is not a *real* generic (like `Array<T>` or `Promise<R>`)! Hope one day I will fully understand this. :)

Comment: Well, okay, I think I think I managed to solve the problem albeit not in a concise way: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wy5YgW).

Answer (score 1):

Your function is best described with two overloads:

```js
// Single prop
declare function omit<O extends Record<string, any>, P extends string>(
    source: O,
    prop: P
): Omit<O, P>

// Array of props
declare function omit<O extends Record<string, any>, P extends string>(
  source: O,
  props: P[]
): Omit<O, P>

// Then...
const o1 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, 'b');

o1.a; // no error - correct
o1.b; // error - correct
o1.c; // no error - correct

const o2 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, ['b', 'c']);

o2.a; // no error - correct!
o2.b; // error - correct
o2.c; // error - correct

// Allow prop values not in `O`
const o3 = omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, ['b', 'c', 'd'])

o3.a; // no error - correct
o3.b; // error - correct
o3.c; // error - correct
o3.d; // error - correct
```

Here's a [link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-H6Kn64JX+YEe9X2rX43VWuiGjBJk24tOW53o7O2jXmulOxkYpO4Uv5itooA) as well.

Comment: Wow. I would never have guessed that `extends (keyof O)` would fix the problem. Very impressive. Thank you! Unfortunately, it has undesirable effect also — `omit({ a: 1, b: 'foo', c: true }, ['b', 'c', 'd'])` produce an error now (sorry I didn't think to highlight this aspect at first).

Comment: I see. I've updated my post to allow props that aren't in the object as well. Looks like the answer was deceivingly simple and jcalz was on the right path here with his comment above. Whether or not you want to split this out into two overloads is purely personal preference at this point.

Comment: Well, apparently, there is very subtle nuance here. My first approach is basically correct, but: 1) `P extends string | string[]` + `props: P` [does not work](https://tsplay.dev/WolXew); 2) `P extends string` + `props: P | P[]` [work](https://tsplay.dev/mqvL2W); 3) 2 × `declare` + `Omit<O, P[number]>` [does not work](https://tsplay.dev/w2KJ8N); 4) 2 × `declare` + `Omit<O, P>` [work again](https://tsplay.dev/NBPDbW)...

Comment: In fact, I did not even know it is possible to pass `string[]` in `Omit` directly (without conversion through `P[number]`... o__o Is this behavior documented?

Comment: @shau-kote This was surprising to me as well. I don't see where you're passing a `string[]`  or a `P` which extends `string[]` directly to `Omit`, but I do see where you have `P[]` as your expected argument to the function. I don't think `Omit` will accept an array type for its second argument.

Comment: Yes, you are right — `Omit` does not support `string[]` or `[string, string]` for its second argument ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wv8eMN)). The "magic" here is that in the my 2nd and 4rd examples above the `P` is declared as `P extends string` (not as array!) and is inferred as a union type of literal string types.